# Is there any way to iterate the dictionary items in django?, I am not getting the ouput

Tags: django, templates

How to iterate the items of the dictionary in django ?

I am developing the Flight Reservation Website using Django. I developed the Passenger Model in models.py as shown below

```
class Passenger(models.Model):

    # Constants in Django Model
    ONE_WAY = "OW"
    MULTI_CITY = 'MC'
    ROUND_TRIP = 'RC'
    TRAVEL_CLASS = (
        (ONE_WAY, 'one_way'),
        (MULTI_CITY, 'multi_city'),
        (ROUND_TRIP, 'round_trip'),
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    trip_choice = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                   choices=TRAVEL_CLASS,
                                   default=ONE_WAY)
    flying_from = models.ForeignKey(Airport, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='start', null=True)
    flying_to = models.ForeignKey(Airport, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='destination', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

I wrote the views.py as shown below

```
def passenger(request):
    passenger = Passenger.objects.filter(id=1)
    context={}
    context['passenger'] = passenger
    context['name'] = 'passenger'
    return render(request, 'passengers.html', context)
```

templates/passengers.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Passenger Information</title>
</head>
<body>
{% if passenger %}
<h1>User is there</h1>
{% for key, value in passenger.items %}
<li>{{key}} -- {{value}} </li>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<h2> No User</h2>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

But, by using above template, I am not able to get the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing a dictionary, rather you are passing a [Queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api-reference) object through context. Hence you need to iterate like this:

```
{% for value in passenger %}
<li>first name -- {{value.first_name}} </li>
<li>lastname -- {{value.last_name}} </li>
{% endfor %}
```

(But) If you want to iterate like a dictionary, then you need to send [values queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#values) to render the template:

```
# view
 passenger = Passenger.objects.filter(id=1).values('first_name', 'last_name')  # it will send a list of dictionaries
context={}
context['passenger'] = passenger

// template
{% for single_passenger in passenger %}  // passenger is a list
    {% for key, value value in single_passenger.items %} // single_passenger is a dictionary
    <li>{{ key }} -- {{value}} </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```